# Delay in how sprite rotates

Tags: java, android, controls, andengine

I'm trying to make this vehicle movement seem more realistic.

This works perfect except for how instant the rotation is.

It could do 180 instantly. I don't want it to turn around so fast.

```
public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
    final Body carBody = CityRacerActivity.this.mCarBody;
    final float rotationInRad = (float)Math.atan2(-pValueX, pValueY);

    if ((pValueX == 0) && (pValueY == 0)) {
        //Don't turn the body/sprite of the car
    }else {
        carBody.setTransform(carBody.getWorldCenter(), rotationInRad);
        //turn the car body in the direction of movement
        CityRacerActivity.this.mCar.setRotation(MathUtils.radToDeg(rotationInRad));
    }

    //set the velocity
    final Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pValueX * 5, pValueY * 5);
    carBody.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);
}
```

I want it to have more play like driving a car.

Comment: where/when are you calling this method?

Comment: This method is used as part of andengine. It creates a digital joystick on the touchscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `setRotation` changes the body's "facing direction" immediately.

You can use `setAngularVelocity` instead. It will also make your game much more reallistic because a car can't really rotate on the spot, so with an angular velocity the car will rotate  during the physics world update, when it also moves according to your regular velociy. So it rotates as it moves, and that what's happening in our world.

I'd give `setAngularVelocity` a parameter depending on how sharp the turn is, 90 degrees should be the maximum IMO (But decide it after your own tests).